# Permissions 0644 for 'id_rsa_bblc' are too open

Tags: php, jenkins, ssh

I am running a job in jenkins. But when I create a build I get below error.

```
Permissions 0644 for 'id_rsa_bblc' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: id_rsa_bblc
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

While googling for a solution I found that I will have to change file permission to 400 or 600. So I tried to build job again after changing permission (using both 400 and 600) but still there is no use, the error still remains.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you share the output of `ls -la` on the folder containing your key?

Comment: Is not suggested for a production environment but can always disable `sshd`'s file permissions check by setting `StrictModes no` in your `sshd_config`. `chmod 600 /path/to/key/id_rsa_bblc && chmod 700 /path/to/key` usually works when `StrictModes yes`.

Comment: where is the sshd_config located? I searched but was not able to find this file.

Comment: @masseyb sshd (server) configuration has no effect on whether the client will read keys from an insecure file.

Answer (score 6):

You need to restrict the access rights to your rsa key

```
 chmod 400 ~/path-to-your-rsa-key
```

Answer (score 0):

`0644` in not supposed to be too open for a public key, but is too open for your private key.

Your private key should have permission `0600` while your public key have permission `0644`.

By the way, you should also take care of the permission on .ssh folder. It should has the permission  `0700`, so that only you, the owner, has control over the folder.

As to your home directory, write permission is not supposed to be granted to group and others.

Run `chmod go-w /home/username` should fix that.

By the way, you should run this on the machine directly not via Jenkins.

Comment: I already tried changing private key permission to 0600 and for home directory only user has write permission. But still it is showing same error.

Comment: Can you create a gist on https://gist.github.com/ after running the command in the directory where your file is located? Just run `ls -la` and you should be able to see if proper permission is given to the file or not.

Comment: I have checked permissions using `ls -la` command and permission is correct i.e 600 but still error is not fixed.

Comment: The very first line itself is telling `Permissions 0644 for 'id_rsa_bblc' are too open` 0644 is not equal to 0600. Can you recheck once again?

Comment: Just run `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to change the permission

Answer (score 0):

If the keys chown/chgrp and chmod info is just correct,
try this:

changing the .pub key to the privkey, e.g.:

in the ~/.ssh/config file:

`identityfile /home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` (OLD)

into

`identityfile /home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519`  (NEW)

And try again.

From this, it looks like in the implementation,
the 'config' file is *assumed* to have the privkey listed,
and when the .pub key is found, *it* is checked for
the permissions the PRIVkey is supposed to have,
throwing the error.
If true, this is a deviation from answers in earlier years,
where people stated the .pub key should be listed.

(my system: Debian 11 bullseye,  openssh-server 1:8.4p1-5)

HTH,
Michael